# Right way of triggering a javascript from html

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

What is the way for having a graphical component (more precisely a twitter.bootstrap icon) in an html website calling a java script.

One could either make a button and putting the icon on it, but this does not look nice IMHO.
Or one could use the href tag,

```
<a href="#" name="ad_fav" onclick= CALLFUNCTION> <i
                        class="icon"></i></a>
```

But what is the cleanest way of achieving this?
It would also be nice if the icon could change after it was clicked.

How it for example the upvote button in stackoverflow implemented?

Comment: stack overflow implemented it with an anchor element styled over CSS (background-image) with classes "vote-up-off" and "vote-up-on" where the later get added by the JavaScript function.

Comment: You can see how SO buttons are implemented by right-clicking and selecting "Inspect Element" (or your browser's equivalent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
function myFunc () {
// code here
}

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("icon");
element[0].addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

Comment: +1; this **is** the cleanest way, without mixing js with html!

Comment: There's no `getElementByClassName()` method. There _is_ a `getElementsByClassName()` (note the plural "s" in "Elements").

Comment: Still not right, getElement*s*ByClassName doesn't return an element, but rather an array of them. I recommend using an id to identify it, that's what id is made for, so have your icon image use id="icon1" and then get it by id, or iterate through all the icon classes

Comment: Adding the click handler to the anchor is a better option since it automatically allows access via the keyboard. The code shown still gives a `Object #<NodeList> has no method 'addEventListener'` error - need to say `element[0].addEventListener(...)` (assuming at least one element matches).

Comment: @nnnnnn - right on, not testing the code out is entirely my mistake. Well spotted!

Answer (score 1):

Just make the href of the <a> be 'javascript:', example:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello there! this works!')" name="ad_fav"> <i
                    class="icon"></i></a>
```

Replace alert(...) with your function call if you need

Answer (score 1):

You don't have do wrap it with an anchor element:

```
<img src="[path to twitter.bootstrap icon]" onclick="yourJavaScriptFunction" />
```

Comment: This is a nice method to do it, but the <a> tag provides a few nice things that don't come with onclick (in CSS), like a clickable mouse cursor that let's you know you can click it

Comment: You don't have to wrap it with an anchor, but you _should,_ because then it will be accessible via the keyboard.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, that's another one of the conveniences provided by the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use jquery on function?

```
$(document).on("click", "a.icon", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```